# How to call JSON decoder from orchestration with JSON input string?

Tags: json, biztalk, jsondecoder, biztalk-2020

In orchestration I have JSON string (retreived from helper class returning string, but can be changed if required).

How can I call custom pipeline (including configuration), including the JSON decoder pipeline component, to get JSON decoded into XML?

Problem seems to be the XLANGMessage of type System.String, which wraps the JSON text into something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<string>
  JSON string
</string>
```

Which causes following error message when running pipeline from orchestration:

```
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

How can I call this custom pipeline with JSON string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options

1. Call a helper class where you can extract the string and call a JSON class directly, rather than trying to use the Pipeline Component
2. Use the Business Rule Engine and have some rules that extract the string and call the Pipeline Component.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with parsing JSON using Newtonsoft library in the helper class directly.